# Zoom in dynamically displayed image with materialbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, materialize

So i'd like to zoom on my dynamically displayed image when I click on it. I'm using cordova and materializecss. I'd like to use the materialbox function. [(materialbox here)](https://materializecss.com/media.html) I've tried many ways but didn't manage to figure it out. Here's my simplified code :
Displaying images :

```
    function createHtmlGall(imgTab) {
    let htmlGall = ""

    imgTab.forEach(function(element) {
        htmlGall += '<div class="col s12 m4 l3">'
        htmlGall += '<img src="' + element + '" class="materialbox responsive-img card">'
        htmlGall += '</div>'
    })
    $( "#imagesDiv" ).html(htmlGall)
}
```

trying to set a zoom effect on click :

```
        $(document).on( "click", ".materialbox").materialbox()
```

I'd like to use jquery if possible.

Comment: with  `$(document).on( "click", ".materialbox", materialbox)`  should work

Comment: Didn't work. Materialbox is then undefined : 
Uncaught ReferenceError: materialbox is not defined
Any clues to why ? ( I did include materialize in my html )